# Get logged in website specific text

Tags: c#, xpath, web, authentication, web-scraping

This is my code for login to website

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_username").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_password").SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_submit").InvokeMember("click");
```

and then i use:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://wzone.ir/");
var HeaderNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"info_dp\"]");
foreach (var item in HeaderNames) {
  label1.Text =  item.InnerText.ToString();
}
```

This code is for getting the text but the program freezes and does nothing.

**EDIT**:Solved with this code:

```
label1.Text=webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("info_dp").InnerText.ToString();
```

Comment: You should debug your code to find the freezing line.

Comment: The information you gave helps us very little to solve your problem. It is too broad. you should debug and narrow down your problem and after that, post it here or edit your quesion .

Comment: **Thank you for you comments** i have edited my post